# Windows Forms Project Save State Issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have to keep about 50-60 static objects of different classes in a forms project. list, string, int, bool contain all kinds of static objects.

I want to save the current state of these static objects when closing the program. I use binaryformatter/filestream classes for this. for example;

```
public static int a;
    public static bool b;
    public static string c;
    public static List<a> d;

    public static void SaveState()
         {
             using (var stream = new FileStream("save1.bin", FileMode.Create))
             {
                 var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                 formatter.Serialize(stream, a);
                 formatter.Serialize(stream, b);
                 formatter.Serialize(stream, c);
                 formatter.Serialize(stream, d);
               
                 stream.Flush();
                 stream.Close();
            }
         }
```

I then call these states with a load method:

```
   public static void LoadStateForm6()
      {
        if (File.Exists("save1.bin"))
          {
            using (var stream = new FileStream("save1.bin", FileMode.Open))
              {
                var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                a= (int)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                b= (bool)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                c= (string)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                d= (List<a>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                   
               }
           }
      }
```

In this way, I call 5-6 similar methods and do more than one save and load operation .

my question is:

Sometimes there is no problem in the save part of this process, sometimes it is interrupted and brings me back to visual studio. When I look at it, I see that it is interrupted while serializing and the process does not go forward. This happens at a different step each time.

Is my computer having difficulty writing this data to the hard disk at this speed? What should I do to prevent this?

```
    public static int a;
    public static bool b;
    public static string c;
    public static List<a> d;

    public static void SaveState()
         {
             using (var stream = new FileStream("save1.bin", FileMode.Create))
             {
                 var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                 formatter.Serialize(stream, a);
                 formatter.Serialize(stream, b);
                 formatter.Serialize(stream, c);
                 formatter.Serialize(stream, d);
               
                 stream.Flush();
                 stream.Close();
            }
         }
```

I then call these states with a load method:

```
public static void LoadStateForm6()
         {
             if (File.Exists("save1.bin"))
             {
                 using (var stream = new FileStream("save1.bin", FileMode.Open))
                 {
                     var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                     a= (int)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                     b= (bool)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                     c= (string)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                     d= (List<a>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                   
                 }
             }
         }
```

Comment: Your code does not look like that it should provoke the behavior you describe. But as a more general answer try to to circumnavigate the BinaryFormatter. a.) it stores type information in a version dependent way. If you update the framework you risk that some types can't be deserialized again (typically more complex types but still).

Comment: and b.) It tries to serialize everything referenced referenced by the type you target also. For example if you try to serialize something that surfaces events and someone else has registered that event that someone else will also be serialized. I would suggest putting everything you want to write into a file into a single class instead of individually properties and then use a standard serializer on that class like the ones for json or xml. The behavior of those are way easier to control.

Comment: What do you mean by "interrupted"? Are you getting an exception, if so, what is it?